# Variance bounded when values of random variable bounded?

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

At the risk of asking something dumb, but I'm reading a paper dealing with random variables, say $X$, assumed only to take values in $[0,1]$, have mean $\mu\in[0,1]$ and variance at least $\sigma^2>0$.

It is then mentioned that the variance of $X$ is at most $1$ "because its values are in $[0,1]$."

My question is: is this obvious? Should I see immediately that this is so?

Comment: Since $X^2≤1$ we have $E[X^2]≤1$.

Comment: Yes, actually $X \in [0,1]\implies Var(X) \leq 1/4$.

Comment: Intuitively, the most "spread out" the distribution could get is for the pdf (or pmf in this case) is to take value $0.5$ at $x=0$ and $0.5$ at $x=1$. At which point the mean is zero and $Var(X) \le \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess. I had the same intuition as in the first comment, i.e., that $E[X^2]\le 1$, and I can certainly show it if, for instance, $X$ is discrete. But I wasn't sure how to make it more rigorous in absence of more information about the distributions and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lulu comment is the easiest way to see $X \in [0,1]\implies Var(X)\leq 1$. Here is a proof of the tighter bound $Var(X)\leq 1/4$.

Claim: If $X \in [0,1]$ and $E[X]=m$, then $m \in [0,1]$ and
$$0\leq Var(X)\leq m(1-m)$$
The upper bound is achieved by $X \sim Bernoulli(m)$.

Proof: Suppose $E[X]=m$ and
$$ 0\leq X \leq 1$$
Taking expectations gives
$$0\leq E[X] \leq 1$$
and so $m\in [0,1]$. Define the function $h:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ h(x) = (x-m)^2 + (2m-1)(x-m)$$
We see that $h$ is convex and $h(0)=h(1)=m(1-m)$.  It follows that
$$h(x) \leq m(1-m) \quad \forall x \in [0,1]$$
Since $X \in [0,1]$ we have
$$ h(X)\leq m(1-m) $$
Taking expectations of both sides gives
$$E[h(X)]\leq m(1-m)$$
But $E[h(X)]=Var(X)$. $\Box$

Maximizing $m(1-m)$ over $m \in [0,1]$ gives the largest possible variance of $Var(X)=1/4$ when $m=1/2$.